# Convert query from SQL into Laravel format

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I need to convert this query into a [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel) query. I have followed the documentation but it is still too confusing and hard to accomplish the task for me. I have searched on Google but cannot find any solution.

```
SELECT u.name , 
           ((SUM(tot_expenseamount)/ SUM(tot_noofmeal))*tot_noofmeal) as total_Cost,
           IFNULL(t.tot_expenseamount,0) AS tot_expense_amount ,
           IFNULL(n.tot_noofmeal,0) AS tot_no_of_meal 
    FROM users u
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT e.user_id , SUM(e.expenseamount) AS tot_expenseamount 
        FROM expenses e 
        WHERE e.expensedate >= '2019-04-01' + INTERVAL 0 MONTH AND e.expensedate < '2019-04-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
        GROUP BY e.user_id ) t ON t.user_id = u.id
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT m.user_id , SUM(m.noofmeal) AS tot_noofmeal 
        FROM meals m 
        WHERE m.mealdate >= '2019-04-01' + INTERVAL 0 MONTH AND 
       m.mealdate < '2019-04-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
        GROUP BY m.user_id ) n ON n.user_id = u.id 
     GROUP BY u.name 
     ORDER BY u.name
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO. The simple answer to your question is "probably" but there is so much unknown here that it would be guessing as to what you want. You seem to have some joins in here so you probably want to define a few models and their relations. You will need to do some work yourself before we can help you effectively. Could you please extend your post to show us what you already tried.

Comment: To build off what @milo526 said there, what would be helpful is a list of your models, your migrations / database tables and your controller function. You can read up on [raw expressions and joins here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#raw-expressions).